Gold given in Mehr at the time of Nikkah
I gave some fold gifts to my fiance before nikah, now at the time of Nikah i want all this gold to ne considered in her Mehr , i am confused about "at what rate gold is to be amounted as the rate of gold keeps increasing"? Please enlighten me in this regard.
Thankyou

When gold is given in mahr it is mentioned in terms of weight and not price.
